# Download numbered image files in numbered folders from internet using python

Tags: python, image, http, loops

**The Problem**

[http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/**1980**/Big/IMG_**2524**.jpg](http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection//1980/Big/IMG_2524.jpg)

I have a link of this type where **1980** is initial folder that's changing and secondly the image filenames in format IMG_**2524**.jpg are changing.

what i wish to do is download all images from these url by iterating and changing these numbers within a range of 1900-2000 in case of folder and IMG_2000.jpg to IMG_4000.jpg in case of filename.
The downloaded files must be saved inside the folder number it comes from.

I think *for* loop should be the option but being a newbie i am somewhat lost. 
please help thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
text_file = open('Output.txt', 'w')
for i in xrange(1900,2001):
    for j in xrange(2000, 4001):
        year = str(i)
        image = str(j)
        new_link = 'http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/'+year+'/Big/IMG_'+image+'.jpg'

        text_file.write(new_link)
text_file.close()
```

thanks to anmol

Comment: Please try writing some code and show us what you've got so far.  Or consider simply using "wget" (either the program or the Python module), which can do things like this already.

Comment: thanks will try it update here soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need two for loops, nested for loops So now we have all `2000 - 4000` images for a given year in range `1900 - 2001`

```
for i in xrange(1900,2001):
    for j in xrange(2000, 4001):
        year = str(i)
        image = str(j)
        new_link = 'http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/'+year+'/Big/IMG_'+image+'.jpg'
        print new_link
        #Now you will get the possible links within the given ranges,
        #then you can use urllib2 to fetch the response from the link 
        # and do whatever you wanna do
```

Sample output:

```
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_3994.jpg
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_3995.jpg
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_3996.jpg
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_3997.jpg
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_3998.jpg
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_3999.jpg
http://www.fdci.org/imagelibrary/EventCollection/2000/Big/IMG_4000.jpg
```

Comment: Its returning a taberror - inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation any ideas ?

Comment: I have attached the sample output, It is working perfectly on my machine, I think there is some error in copying and pasting, Try writing this small piece of code by yourself and give the relevant indentation.

Comment: hi thanks for that, i have written a piece of code to store the strings in  a filename output.txt but its returning tab error please check the update

Comment: thanks a lot, one last thing how to make them write on to the next line

Comment: replace `text_file.write(new_link)` by `text_file.write(new_link + '\n')`

Comment: no problem i fixed it myself, thanks a lot you rock dude ! Cheers to python